# How to send chunks of data into a Sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, cron, real-time

I have a sensor that reads voltage data, and i have an envelope function that envelopes a fixed chunk of data. I currently have a sqlite database linked to a cron job, that reads sensor value at certain time intervals to put it into the database.

however, i would like to have the cron job input a chuck of processed data into the database instead of raw voltage. is this possible through sqlite?. is it possible to create an array -> append sensor values into the array -> perform the envelop function -> spit out a array of processed voltage values -> send that array to the database table named "volts".

Comment: what's the schema of the db? what would be the point of storing multiple values together in one row?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)